# Zend Framework 2 & Doctrine 2 – how to properly save a form / Hydration?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

Using Zend Framework 2, I've build a simple form and a corresponding Doctrine 2 entity. Now I am wondering how I correctly save the form using Doctrine.

If I understood correctly, I can use a hydrator for that – the posted data in array format will be transformed into an object which then can be handled by Doctrine (or something like that), is this correct?

Currently my form looks like this:

```
use Zend\Form\Form;

class MyForm extends Form
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct('MyForm');

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'firstName',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'First Name',
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'submit',
            'name' => 'submit',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => Submit'
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => 'Submit Form',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

And the entity like this:

```
class Form
{
    protected $firstName;

    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the field name matches the corresponding variable in the entity. Is this required? I got it to work like this with the following controller code, but I don't really think it's the right approach:

```
use SomeForm\Form\MyForm;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;

class FormsController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        $entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager);
        $request = $this->getRequest();
        $form = new MyForm();
        $form->setHydrator($hydrator);
        $entity = new \SomeForm\Entity\Form();
        $form->bind($entity);

        if ($request->isPost()) {
            $data = $request->getPost();
            $form->setData($data);

            // Nothing is validated here
            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $entityManager->persist($entity);
                $entityManager->flush();
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

While doing a research on how this works, I also encountered code examples that contain a function called `populate` in the entity that maps the forms' post data to the entity. Do I need such a function? How can I change the field names without breaking anything? Is my code correct or am I doing things not how they are supposed to be?

I know ZF2 has a `ClassMethods` hydrator that uses the entities getter/setter methods – is Doctrine 2 doing the same?

Comment: Most of the hard stuff looks right. It looks like why the form not isValid needs digging into.

Comment: Have you declared your entity as a doctrine entity e.g. `@ORM\Entity` and mapped the variables correctly?

Comment: @Svengali Yes I've done that. I can also write to & read from the database, I just don't really know how to use the hydrator properly. In some way, the form input and database fields/entity properties need to be connected but I am not sure how to do that. I've seen some examples that use a `populate` function or exchange arrays, but I am skeptical if it's correct to use them with a hydrator together.